# How I can select a value in my Android ListView and send this Information to a other Activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity, galaxy

Hi I want to built a android a application with a ListView and if I select a value in this ListView I want to start a other activity with this value. The Problem is I don't know how I can click on a value in my ListView and the other activity get the informations. Here is my Code:

My First Activity:

```
package de.android.shilfe;

import de.android.shilfe.DatenbankManager;
import de.android.shilfe.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase mDatenbank;
    private DatenbankManager mHelper;

    private static final String KLASSEN_SELECT_ROW = 
            "SELECT _id, name FROM Stundenplan";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHelper.STUNDENPLAN_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE Stundenplan(" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                "name TEXT NOT NULL)";

       mHelper = new DatenbankManager(this);

       //what I must do here ??? :(
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mDatenbank.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, 
                getResources().getString(R.string.db_close),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {     
        super.onResume();

        mDatenbank = mHelper.getReadableDatabase(); //Datenbank öffnen

        Toast.makeText(this, 
                getResources().getString(R.string.db_open),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        ladeDaten();
    }

    private void ladeDaten() {
        Cursor KlassenCursor = mDatenbank.rawQuery(KLASSEN_SELECT_ROW, null); // Gibt ein Index zurück
        startManagingCursor(KlassenCursor); //Durchläuft diesen

        android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter KlassenAdapter = new android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                KlassenCursor, 
                new String[] {"name"},
                new int[] {
                android.R.id.text1
                });

        setListAdapter(KlassenAdapter);


    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view){

        EditText et =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        ContentValues werte = new ContentValues();
        werte.put("name",et.getText().toString());

        mDatenbank.insert("stundenplan", null, werte);

        ladeDaten();
        et.setText("");
    }

}
```

My First Activity Layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/create_defaulttext">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/sf_daten_datenbanken_einfuegen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sf_daten_datenbanken_einfuegen"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    </ListView>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tx_daten_datenbank_leer"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I try it in a other Application with this code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List valueList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            valueList.add("value" + i); 
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,valueList); 

        final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); 

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){  
                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.setClassName(getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".Show_Activity"); 
                 intent.putExtra("selected",lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString()); 
                 startActivity(intent); 

             }

         });




    }
```

but in the other Application I fill the ListView by a EditText Control

[image]

I need help :(

Answer (score 1):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){  
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Show_Activity.class);
         intent.putExtra("selected", (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position)); 
         startActivity(intent); 
     }
});
```

You already did pass the value to another activity with `putExtra`

Answer (score 0):

Hey You question is not complete but I am giving this answer as per what I understand. In the onListItemClick() method last parameter of long datatype is id of a row selected. in your case, it will _id of table. If you have 10 rows in your table with id 10 to 20 and displayed the same in listview. Now if you click on 5 item then its id will be 15 which was stored in database. Pass this value to next intent and fetch the details of that row and display in the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a ListActivity so you can use [onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) method.This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.

Answer (score -1):

You can to create a custom list adapter and handle the onClick event in the getView method of the adapter.  The item will be available in this method.

```
public class AccountListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Account> {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        final Account item = this.getItem(position);

        // item = the particular list item you clicked      

           // layoutItem = layout view passed into the adapter
           layoutItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   callActivity(item);
               }
            });

    }




}
```

While handling the event, create an intent with extras and pass the value(s) you desire via the extras.  You can use a simplelistadapter, but this way gives you considerably more control and power!